# JSON Data NULL special Character "&"

Tags: json, web-services, nsjsonserialization

Currently I have a string that I want to POST to a URL.

It works perfectly fine except when it encounters special characters like "&". It will POST other data that comes after that. For example, I have a string "Chang & hong" in Brand text, by selecting the Model Value depends upon Brand text am parsing the URL as

```
post=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://moneytree.com.au/rest-webservice/rest/&Brand=%@",StrbrandSelect1];

NSURL *url;
 url = [NSURL URLWithString:[post
                            stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSMutableURLRequest *RequestSubject=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

[RequestSubject setURL:url];
[RequestSubject setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSLog(@"RequestSubject %@",RequestSubject);
Typedata1 = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:RequestSubject
                                  returningResponse:Nil error:Nil];
if (RequestSubject)
{
    NSDictionary *Dictjson = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:Typedata1
                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:nil];

    NSLog(@"The JSON outPut is:%@",Dictjson);

    NSLog(@"The Array Count is: %d",[Dictjson count]);
```

but the Array Count is: 0

Select the data depends upon the Brand "Chang & hong"

I need the output data depends upon brand string the Model Text - "Plasma" and "LCD".

Please Help me out.

Comment: Did you try going to that address manually in the browser and see what pops up? Does the web service belong to you(did you code it?)

Comment: This link leads me nowhere, I think you forgot to replace the %@

Comment: @YoavSchwartz: Can u edit in the code. Thanks.

Comment: Chang%20%26%20hong. replace the & with %26 like you did here in code and I'm guessing it would work

Comment: can you tell me where i need to replace or add?

Answer (score 0):

When you send a URL, there are certain characters which are "not allowed" or have another meaning. for example every space should be %20 and for example a "&" sign would be %26 because otherwise its interpreted by the server as going to the next variable, just like you wouldn't use a "/" sign because the browser would mistake it for a link to somewhere else. if you send Brand=Chang%20&%20hong, the server would treat the part after the & as a new variable. that why you replace this with Chang%20%26%20hong.

Another example using the url you used:

```
?CountryName=Australia&appliance=Television&Brand=Chang%20%26%20hong
```

the literal '&' signs are use to separate different variables for the server, in this case : CountryName,appliance and Brand. when you use a literal '&' in your message you are making it think that %20hong is a new variable.

Comment: :i Can't add the URL directly in the coding. (if directly added the array is null). For EX: If the user selected the chang&hong brand, the model will show depends brand selection, so i already encoded NSUTF8StringEncoding. Please help me how to replace it by the way of coding.

Comment: can you post a nslog of the variable "url". because using stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding should have worked, also try manually replacing the & sign in the StrbrandSelect1 variable with %26 and see if it works(I know, its a bandaid not a solution, its just to identify the problem)

Comment: I cant receive any NSlog data. But the ouput will be depend chang & hong ={ "parentkey":[[{"Type":"LCD (LED)"}]]}. If i parse directly the data will become Null.